# Overheating problem with HP Pavilion G6 2231tx

Tags: 12.04, overheating, hp-pavilion

I have overheating problem with HP pavilion G6 on ubuntu, but I don't have any issues on Windows 8. My CPU is Intel i3, 2.4 Ghz.

Comment: You should add more information about your CPU.

Comment: Have you looked at http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/overheating+hp-pavilion ?

Answer (score -1):

Download the proprietry drivers available for intel. Search for additional drivers and install the suggested one. Also you can download the driver from intel website.

Comment: Please add links to sources and point out some key points to install drivers properly.